# Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesAndResourcesWithR8ForRelease'. while trying to get apk of flutter app

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart

I tried to get APK of my flutter app using

> flutter build APK

but it returned this error. I have no idea what does it means. I will be glad if you try to help me. comment in this post if you need any extra details to solve the error

> Running Gradle task 'assembleRelease'...
>   R8: Type com.google.firebase.iid.zzbb is referenced as an interface from com.google.firebase.messaging.zzf.
>
> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> - What went wrong:
>     Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesAndResourcesWithR8ForRelease'.
>     com.android.tools.r8.CompilationFailedException: Compilation failed to complete
> - Try:
>     Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run wit
>     h --scan to get full insights.
> - Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
>
> BUILD FAILED in 7m 32s
>   Running Gradle task 'assembleRelease'...
>   Running Gradle task 'assembleRelease'... Done                     456.4s (!)
>   [!] The shrinker may have failed to optimize the Java bytecode.
>       To disable the shrinker, pass the `--no-shrink` flag to this command.
>       To learn more, see: https://developer.android.com/studio/build/shrink-code
>   Gradle task assembleRelease failed with exit code 1

Comment: Hi were you able to solve this?

Comment: yea, i changed the complile sdk version of all installed packages to 28 and  it worked smoothly

Comment: What was your version before that?

Comment: it was 26 earlier, i changet it to 27 to make it work

Answer (score 1):

I'm answering this question because it was one of the first results I got when I searched for the error message.

I had the same error. [`R8`](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2018/11/r8-new-code-shrinker-from-google-is.html) turns out to be a "shrinker" of binary java files and it was masking the issue behind the error. In `gradle.properties`, I change `android.enableR8` from `true` to `false` then rebuilt the apk. I got a different error:

```
...
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:checkReleaseDuplicateClasses'.
> 1 exception was raised by workers:
  java.lang.RuntimeException: Duplicate class androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelLazy found in modules lifecycle-viewmodel-2.4.0-runtime.jar (androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel:2.4.0) and lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx-2.2.0-runtime.jar (androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:2.2.0)
  Duplicate class androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProviderKt found in modules lifecycle-viewmodel-2.4.0-runtime.jar (androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel:2.4.0) and lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx-2.2.0-runtime.jar (androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:2.2.0)

  Go to the documentation to learn how to <a href="d.android.com/r/tools/classpath-sync-errors">Fix dependency resolution errors</a>.
...
```

The error was because I had two versions of lifecycle-viewmodel runtime: 2.2.0 and 2.4.0. I searched the project and plugins and turns out that only one of them uses V2.4.0 and the rest are using V2.2.0:

```
    def lifecycle_version = "2.4.0"
    def arch_version = "2.1.0"

    // ViewModel
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel:$lifecycle_version"
    // LiveData
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata:$lifecycle_version"
    // Lifecycles only (without ViewModel or LiveData)
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime:$lifecycle_version"
```

I just changed `lifecycle_version` to `2.2.0` and I was able to build the apk with no errors.

Don’t forget to turn `android.enableR8` back to `true`.